# Javascript defining a dom object as a variable

Tags: javascript, css, variables, dom, getelementbyid

```
document.getElementById("sgun").style.backgroundColor = "#00FA9A";
```

I would like to define document.getElementById and style.backgroundColor = "#00FA9A"; as a variable, so the code doesn't look horrible, and i don't have to copy-paste that for every element. How to do i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make a function that take an ID and a style and do it for you like:

```
function css(id, prop, value){
    document.getElementById(id).style[prop] = value;
}
```

and then use it like:

```
css('sgun', 'backgroundColor', '#00FA9A');
// css(...);
```

And if you want a function that changes just the background color to '#00FA9A' use this:

```
function bg(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = '#00FA9A';
}
```

and use it like:

```
bg('sgun');
bg('someotherid');
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise making it a function.

```js
function changeBgColor(el) {
 document.getElementById(el).style.backgroundColor = '#00fa9a';
}  
changeBgColor('foo');
changeBgColor('bar');
```

```html
<div id="foo">asdf</div>
<div id="bar">asdf</div>
```